# including submodule assembly artifacts in another module's assembly?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multimodule project such as:

```
top
 |----sub1/
 |----sub2/
 |----packager/
```

sub1 and sub2 have multiple assemblies attached.   Let's say sub1's assemblies creates `target/dist/artifactA.jar` and `target/dist/artifactB.jar`

If I create another assembly in `packager`, how can I pull in artifactA and artifactB from `sub1`, etc?

If I use this including `groupId:artifactId:type:classifier` as below, I get the error: "You must set at least one file".

Even if this did work, this isn't exactly what I want, anyway.  I want the versions of the files in sub1/target/dist, which don't have version or artifactIds on them (as per sub1's assembly configuration).

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>my-distribution</id>

<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
        <binaries>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <includes>
                <include>com.example:sub1:jar:artifactA</include>
                <include>com.example:sub1:jar:artifactB</include>
            </includes>
        </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

**edit**:  looks like `<moduleset>` works only if the sub modules are directly below the module doing the assembling.   `<dependencyset>` is recommended in my case... but I still have the problem of rounding up attached jars that are not the primary jar.

Comment: what is the purpose of `artifactX.jar`? It seems like you are abusing the system.

Comment: @Michael-O two jars created by an assembly in sub1 with some overlap that for classloading purposes must absolutely be in separate jars.   How is it abusing the system to want to use attached artifacts created by an assembly in one module in another module?  artifactA and artifactB show up in `~/.m2/repository/com.example.sub1...` just fine.

Comment: I see usecase seems to OK. Most people abuse it. Have you attached the assemblies?